# Mapped Id using StringObjectIdGenerator produces string _id in database

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm moving over my code to the new 2.0 driver, and having an issue with ObjectIds.

Previously I had decorated string Id properties with BsonId and BsonRepresentation attributes.

Now i'm using class maps

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Model>(cm =>
{
   cm.MapIdMember(p => p.Id).SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
   cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
   cm.AutoMap();
});
```

model is really simple in this example

```
public class Model
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime UpdatedTs { get; set; }
}
```

however after inserting, I get the object id back as string, but it's also a string on the server.

[Image of MongoVue objectid is string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffhq0.png)

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: can you use ObjectIdGenerator instead of StringObjectIdGenerator?

Comment: i could do, but it would mean changing my string _id mapped properties to ObjectId. Something i'd rather not do.  The previous driver was just `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
  public String Id { get; set; }` - no ideas why it wouldnt be working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, thanks to some feedback from Craig on the mongodb driver team, the solution I got working was:

```
cm.MapIdMember(p => p.Id)
  .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance)
  .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId));
```

Like when decorating the properties of the Id property, you need to set the Representation which in v 2.0 you do by SetSerializer

HTH